# Robotframework: select value on rzslider rz-bar-wrapper

Tags: angular, robotframework

I want to click on bar wrapper with robot framework 
I have tried many things but it doesn't work
Thanks for help

Robotframework: select value on rzslider rz-bar-wrapper

[image]code in html
    0 100000 22700

Comment: you need to both show us what you've tried and what the results or errors are.

Comment: On robotframework I want to clique on a bar

Comment: I have add the code HTML,

Comment: I have add the code HTML, I want to clique on the bar with robotframework

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="map-fencing">
            <p ng-hide="!fencingTriggerCtrl.mySelectedPois.length" class="">
                <label for="distance" class="ng-binding">
                    <span translate="" class="ng-scope">Distance</span>
                    (km) * :
                    <span class="ng-binding">11.7</span>
                    <!-- {{myNewAlertDefinition.alertRules[0].fencingTrigger.distance ? myNewAlertDefinition.alertRules[0].fencingTrigger.distance: 0}} -->
                </label>
                <span ng-hide="true" class="ng-binding ng-hide">{"floor":0,"ceil":100000,"step":100,"precision":2}</span>
                <rzslider rz-slider-model="myNewAlertDefinition.alertRules[0].fencingTrigger.distance" rz-slider-options="fencingTriggerCtrl.distanceSlider.options" rz-slider-ceil="100000" ng-hide="mode === 'VIEW'" class="ng-isolate-scope"><span class="rz-bar-wrapper"><span class="rz-bar"></span></span> <span class="rz-bar-wrapper" style="opacity: 0; width: 54.354px; left: 0px;"><span class="rz-bar rz-selection" ng-style="barStyle"></span></span> <span class="rz-pointer rz-pointer-min" ng-style="minPointerStyle" role="slider" aria-valuenow="11700" aria-valuetext="11700" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100000" tabindex="0" style="left: 42.354px;"></span> <span class="rz-pointer rz-pointer-max" ng-style="maxPointerStyle" style="display: none;"></span> <span class="rz-bubble rz-limit" style="opacity: 1;">0</span> <span class="rz-bubble rz-limit" style="opacity: 1; left: 326.609px;">100000</span> <span class="rz-bubble" style="opacity: 1; left: 29.6977px;">11700</span> <span class="rz-bubble" style="opacity: 0;"></span> <span class="rz-bubble" style="opacity: 0;"></span><ul ng-show="showTicks" class="rz-ticks ng-hide"><!-- ngRepeat: t in ticks track by $index --></ul></rzslider>
                <span class="field-info ng-binding">The distance (in kilometers) from the chosen POI (below) to consider as the POI area.</span>
            </p>
            <!--div id="mapWrapper"-->
            <ng-map categories="categories" corridors="[]" is-allow-create-poi="false" is-allow-create-poly="false" ng-vehicles="[]" pois="fencingTriggerCtrl.mySelectedPois" polygon-categories="categories" polygons="fencingTriggerCtrl.mySelectedPolygons" language="userPreferences.language" show-satellite="true" class="ng-isolate-scope"><div id="map">
```

© 1987–2017 HERE, Deutschland | Terms of use | Report imageChoose viewMap ViewSatelliteTerrainTraffic conditionsPublic transportShow traffic incidents5 km5 km

                
                
                </div>
        </div-->